# how to create a contruct() in codeigniter4 controller?

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
class Home extends BaseController
{
    var $cache;

    public function __contruct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->cache = \Config\Services::cache();
    }
    public function reset()
    {
        $this->cache->clean();
    }
}
```

assume i have create a web cache.

the idea is i dont want to keep assign the same $cache in every method.

So contructor should do the job.

but when i load the page, it shows -> Undefined variable: cache

how to fix my code/this issue?

Comment: Try to define cache variable with access modifier like: private $cache.

Comment: Alredy tried with public as well. Not wrking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like codeigniter have already created a constructor method in the BaseController.

Therefore, i just load the function that i wish to preload/initialized in that BaseController.php.

Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

```
    class Home extends \CodeIgniter\Controller
         {
                public function __construct(...$params)
            {
             parent::__construct(...$params);

                 // Your own constructor code
               }
    }
```

Comment: Isnt basecontroller is the namespace for that as well?